# Flask WTForms new inputs are not overwriting prepopulated data upon submission

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I have a flask WTForms form which I am prepopulating with fields from my DB. From there I want to enable the user to update the values of any fields if they choose and re-insert this into the database. The specific issue I'm having with the below sample code is that when I submit the form, there is no data seen in the form.data dictionary (printed on line 18). Those fields are empty even though I've typed information into them. My guess is that form.field1.data is still holding the value it did from the database (line 11), and not taking in the data which the user has typed in.

However I cannot figure out how to otherwise structure the form in order to handle this. code below, thanks

```
@hp_blueprint.route('/formpage',methods=['GET','POST'])
def build_form():

    #setup the QualitativeForm with values from the DB as placeholders
    with sfsql_engine.connect() as conn:
        df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE 1=1",conn)
    if len(df) == 0:
        form = QualitativeForm()
    else:
        form = QualitativeForm()
        form.field1.data = df['field1'].values[0]
        form.field2.data = df['field2'].values[0]
        form.field3.data = df['field3'].values[0]

    #write to DB upon submission
    if form.is_submitted() and form.validate():
        #WHEN I PRINT THIS OUT, IT DOES NOT HOUSE ANY OF THE DATA THAT I JUST TYPED IN
        print(form.data)
        print("the form update worked properly")
        field1 = form.field1.data
        field2 = form.field2.data
        field3 = form.field3.data

        with sfsql_engine.connect() as conn:
            conn.execute("INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(field1,field2,field3) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)",
                      field1,field2,field3)
        print("inserts ran correctly")
        return redirect('/formpage')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it looks like you are overwriting the values of the form in your else statement - the code will be executed both in the "get" and in the "post" case. Therefore, I would change the order of both blocks and rewrite it like this:

```
@hp_blueprint.route('/formpage',methods=['GET','POST'])
def build_form():

    form = QualitativeForm()

    #write to DB upon submission
    if form.is_submitted() and form.validate():
        #WHEN I PRINT THIS OUT, IT DOES NOT HOUSE ANY OF THE DATA THAT I JUST TYPED IN
        print(form.data)
        print("the form update worked properly")
        field1 = form.field1.data
        field2 = form.field2.data
        field3 = form.field3.data

        with sfsql_engine.connect() as conn:
            conn.execute("INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(field1,field2,field3) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)",
                      field1,field2,field3)
        print("inserts ran correctly")
        return redirect('/formpage')

    #setup the QualitativeForm with values from the DB as placeholders
    with sfsql_engine.connect() as conn:
        df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE 1=1",conn)

    if len(df) > 0:
        form.field1.data = df['field1'].values[0]
        form.field2.data = df['field2'].values[0]
        form.field3.data = df['field3'].values[0]

    # return the template with the form or continue with the code...
```

Comment: this worked perfectly, i was just caught up in how i was originally instantiating the form. thanks for the help!